# What does a moderator do?

Tags: classical-latin, vocabulary, history

Classical Latin has the word [*moderator*](http://latinlexicon.org/definition.php?p1=2036469), which refers to someone who manages, rules, governs, directs, or moderates.
I assume it does not refer to all kinds of managers, governors and such.
I also assume a moderator in Rome did not listen to all discussions in the various forums and make sure they stay on the respective topics.
(I know it would make no sense.)

What did the word *moderator* mean for the Romans?
I am not convinced that mere listed translations will capture the spirit of the word, so I would like to see a better description.
What kinds of people could be referred to as *moderatores*?
Is there some kind of management or leadership that is outside the area of a *moderator*?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Though it is true that a *moderator* is a rough equivalent of similar "governing" words like *dux, curator,* or *arbiter*, there is an important nuance that should be kept in mind when using it.

An important clue comes from its provenance: it is a verbal noun derived from [*moderor, -ari*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dmoderor), which has a specific literal meaning:

> **I. Lit.**:  moderate, mitigate, restrain, allay, temper, qualify

This literal meaning obviously comes from [*modus, -i*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dmodus):

> A measure which is not to be exceeded, a bound, limit, end, restriction

It is only in light of this literal meaning that the "governing" meaning came to be:

> **II. Transf.**: to manage, regulate, rule, guide, govern, direct

My contention is that *many* uses (though certainly not all) carry the important nuance of *limitation* or *restraint*: if I am correct, a *moderator militum* is more concerned with making sure they do not step out of line, rather than leading them in a charge, as a *dux* or *imperator* might be. One good example where *moderator* is appropriate but other words are not is from Ovid, who is describing a horrible sickness and then remarks:

> Non stratum, non ulla pati velamina possunt,
>   dura sed in terra ponunt praecordia; nec fit
>   corpus humo gelidum, sed humus de corpore fervet.
>   **Nec moderator adest**, inque ipsos saeva medentes
>   erumpit clades... (Ov *Meta* 7:558-562)

My translation:

> They cannot bear any coverlet or sheets,
>   but instead place their bodies on the hard earth; nor does their body
>   cool down in contact with the ground, but the ground heats up from their body.
>   **Nor is there any one to provide relief**, since the raging illness
>   has infected the healers themselves.

To summarize:

1. There is no specific public or private function referred to by *moderator*.
2. A *moderator* is one who provides a *modus* to something.

   a. This can be **figurative**, in which case its meaning isn't much different from other "governing" words, or:

   b. This can be **literal**, in which case it specifically refers to *restraint* (*moderator libidinis*) or limitation.

Comment: Interestingly, your answer is a good description what a moderator does on SE. Their main duty is to make sure that behavior stays within certain limits, not so much to lead into any particular direction.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta I thought they were more of a caretaker than a true, [internet-]forum-style moderator.

Comment: @cmw It's true that all users can participate in the traditional internet-forum-moderator duties and the moderators just make sure things work as they should. Taking care and setting boundaries is essentially the same thing here, since the SE team is responsible for all things technical. Aspects and viewpoints change, but it seems most online moderators do what a Roman *moderator* would.

Answer (score 7):

I think that *moderator* had no very specific meaning beyond the one for the context in which a particular  example might be found. Would the word *controller* make a more comprehensive translation? Contrary to what you seem to be suggesting, it can replace any one or other of your five given examples, to which you might also add *restrainer*: in other words, *moderator* could provide a decent alternative to *gubernator*, *curator*, *dux*, *administrator* and so on, more or less at the writer's whim.

Ovid uses it, for example, for a handler of tools or instruments (Meta. VIII.856), or animals (Meta. IV, 245), where in each instance he may have rejected, say, *actor* to satisfy either metre or style.

I have no idea that a *moderator* did as you choose not to assume, by regulating discussions in the Forum, etc. — and there you have another possibility in *regulator* —though I can scarcely believe that such a busybody would have been given much shrift!

Comment: You can add *procurator* and, getting a little metaphorical, *arbiter*, too.

Comment: Quite! and others, I should think.