# What are auscultatores?

Tags: vocabulary, latin-to-english-translation, modern-life, nuntii-latini

In honor of the last broadcast of the *Nuntiī Latinī*:

> Nuntii Latini Radiophoniae Finnicae Generalis, qui inde ab anno millesimo nongentesimo undenonagesimo (1989) iam triginta annos septimanatim emittuntur, post hanc emissionem finiuntur et decreto moderatorum radiophonicorum post ferias aestivas non continuabuntur. Auscultatoribus, quorum grex ad omnes orbis continentes amplificatus est, propter fidelitatem gratias quam maximas agimus et valedicimus.

My attempt at a literal translation:

> Latin Announcements on the General Finnish Radio, which ever since the year 1989 has been broadcast weekly for thirty years now, after this transmission, will be be ended, and, by the decree of the radio regulators, it will not be continued after the summer holidays. To our [???], the group of whom has grown to [cover] all the continents of the world, we send the greatest possible thanks for your faithfulness, and wish you farewell.

Or more idiomatically:

> Latin Announcements on the General Finnish Radio, which has been broadcast weekly for thirty years since 1989, will be ending after this transmission—and the regulators have decided not to continue it after this summer. To our [???], who are now spread across every continent in the world, we send our most heartfelt thanks—and wish you farewell.

Is this correct? And more specifically, what are these *auscultatoribus* who are being thanked? From context, it seems like they're "listeners" or "followers", but I can't even begin to parse the Latin word.

(I'm also unsure about *moderatores* being "regulators", but it's the closest I could think of based on [this question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/2149/what-does-a-moderator-do).)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Listeners. It's an agent noun made from ausculto.